# A variable as part of array name

Tags: bash

I have this little piece of code:

```
#!/bin/bash

item01=('item1' '1' '20')
item02=('item2' '4' '77')
item03=('item3' '17' '15')
zeroone=01
zerotwo=02


echo ""
declare -a array=()
array=${item$zeroone[@]}
echo ""
echo ${array[@]}
echo ""
```

Obviously this doesn't work (bad substitution).

Is there a way to make it work? Such that a variable can be a part of an array name?

And also, to make this work in particular:

```
array[0]=${item$zeroone[0]}
```

and

```
another_variable=${item$zeroone[0]}
```

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Better use associative arrays:**

```
declare -A item=([1, 0]='item1' [1, 1]='1' [1, 2]='20')
...
```

Accessing an element:

```
one=1
echo "${item[$one, 0]}"
```

On a loop:

```
for ((I = 0; I <= 2; ++I)); do
    echo "${item[$one, $i]}"
done
```

You can also use strings instead of numbers:

```
declare -A item=(["01", 0]='item1' ["01", 1]='1' ["01", 2]='20')
```

**Another answer: You can actually use references:**

```
item01=('item1' '1' '20')
item02=('item2' '4' '77')
item03=('item3' '17' '15')
zeroone=01
zerotwo=02

echo ""
ref="item${zeroone}[@]"
declare -a array=("${!ref}")  ## Still produces 3 arguments as if "${item01[@]}" was called
echo ""
echo "${array[@]}"
echo ""
```